# Pharo 3.0 OmniBrowser

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I could not download the package browser O2PackageBrowserAdaptor // OmniBrowser for the Pharo 3.0 , Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you indicate in your post where\how you tried to download this package?  It may offer some guidance for others on where you are having trouble downloading from..

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK OmniBrowser is no longer supported in Pharo 3.

If you want to browse the Pharo system use the new Pharo standard browser Nautilus. It is already included in Pharo 3.

If you want to build your own browsers there is an excellent browser scripting framework called Glamour.

You can load Glamour via Smalltalkhub: http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~Moose/Glamour
and learn about it by reading the [Deep into Pharo](http://www.deepintopharo.com) chapter on Glamour.